Diodes parallel sensing resistor in boost PFC circuit
Can someone tell me the functions of diodes paralleled with the PFC boost sensing resistor?

Source: https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-down/R/8/C/R8CB05BO-Champion.pdf

(The question has been reopened now that the OP has supplied a link to the source of the schematic (which is also the IC datasheet) and no other details were requested by those who VTC.)

Inrush protection. Notice what happens under startup or surge conditions, as mains charges the 180uF capacitor.
Namely, protection for the controller, so it doesn't see large voltage at the sense input pin, but perhaps also to protect the resistor in case it doesn't have an adequate surge rating itself.
There's another pair of diodes at the controller, which makes me wonder if this wasn't the best-conceived design, or if the controller is especially sensitive to current flow.  A check of the datasheet may prove illuminating.

It's out of scope but, what about the switch section? It's kinda floating. Or am I missing something?

@RohatKılıç Yeah, someone missed a wire there big time. There's probably several things to review proper; the lack of designators doesn't help either.
